# Retrieve data from a Table to the Cclipboard

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Goal:
Retrieve the value of the table and its html from  to the  when you click on the linktext "On click".
The data from the table should be used for pasting inside of a Excel document.

Problem:
I tried different solution but it doesn't work.

Do you know how to solve it?

Information:
*The code works only in IE!
*Please remember that the value of the table can be differn because you bring the data from the database.
*I'm using ASP.net mvc 4
*"http://jsbin.com/ridedugeye/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output"

```js
var elem3 = document.getElementById('test3');
 

elem3.onclick = function () {
    document.execCommand('copy');
}

elem3.addEventListener('copy', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.clipboardData) {
        e.clipboardData.setData('text/plain', 'custom content from clickk');
    } else if (window.clipboardData) {
        window.clipboardData.setData('Text',
                                    'ddddd');
    }

});
```

```html
  <div id='test3'>On click</div>

  
  
  
<table border="1" id="asdf">
<tr>
    <td>aaa</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
    <td>ccc</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I've never worked with these kinds of things, but it looks like [`clipboardData.setData()` is deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535220(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Also, I'm in Chrome and clicking the `div.test3` seems to give me `"custom content from clickk"` in my clipboard. Doesn't that mean it's working just like how it's supposed to?

Comment: WHAT! I'm surprized. I don't know what to say

Comment: Hm...It doesn't seem to be working in Mozilla, though.

Comment: OK, in Mozilla, the `"copy"` event is working, but the call to `document.execCommand()` gives me an `NS_ERROR_FAILURE` in my JavaScript console. I have absolutely no idea what that means!